# Introspection to get decorator names on a method?

Tags: python, decorator, introspection

I am trying to figure out how to get the names of all decorators on a method. I can already get the method name and docstring, but cannot figure out how to get a list of decorators.

Comment: This seems needless.  You have the source.  What's wrong with reading the source?

Comment: @S.Lott: couldn't you answer the same way about any question involving introspection?  And yet introspection is useful.

Comment: @S.Lott: Nothing is wrong with reading the source, much the same as nothing is wrong with reading the contents of a database directly instead of using views or scripting, unless I want automation. I use decorators for authentication and I am generating reports with different views to show what user groups have access to which resources. So I need programmatic access to the source, the same as I need programmatic access to a data source.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: I'm not "answering" -- at least I don't think I am.  I'm asking what the use case is.  Introspection is something the lawyers call an "attractive nuisance".  I don't get the use case for this example of introspection.  The question is too short and thin on details.

Comment: That's not a very helpful clarification.  Can you provide some use case and some code?

Comment: A little late to the game here, but a very good reason for this is documentation. In Django, for example, there is a decorator that a lot of people use: `@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST', ])`. In addition to printing out a docstring for a method, it could be nice to print out the http_methods that a method implements.

Comment: Being even more late, but another use case is unit testing api endpoints. If you have authorization checks as decorators you don't need to setup every test for every endpoint for those. Just test the decorators separately and check if the actually tested endpoint is decorated with that or not. Naturally if you have fake authorization decorators with the same name declared, you can cheat yourself into believing the endpoint is safe. So this requires some clean design behavior beforehand.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you can change the way you call the decorators from

```
class Foo(object):
    @many
    @decorators
    @here
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

to

```
class Foo(object):
    @register(many,decos,here)
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

then you could register the decorators this way:

```
def register(*decorators):
    def register_wrapper(func):
        for deco in decorators[::-1]:
            func=deco(func)
        func._decorators=decorators        
        return func
    return register_wrapper
```

For example:

```
def many(f):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwds):
        return f(*args,**kwds)
    return wrapper

decos = here = many

class Foo(object):
    @register(many,decos,here)
    def bar(self):
        pass

foo=Foo()
```

Here we access the tuple of decorators:

```
print(foo.bar._decorators)
# (<function many at 0xb76d9d14>, <function decos at 0xb76d9d4c>, <function here at 0xb76d9d84>)
```

Here we print just the names of the decorators:

```
print([d.func_name for d in foo.bar._decorators])
# ['many', 'decos', 'here']
```

Comment: This is a great solution. :D It does assume you have access to the code that's assigning the decorators, though...

Comment: Ok this could work, but why can't I just add the code func._whatever='something' into my existing decorator, and test for the value of the _whatever attribute when performing introspection on the method?

Comment: You can, but then you'll have to dirty every decorator you write with the cross-cutting concern of leaving its tracks behind in the function it modifies.

Comment: This basically works only for your custom `@register` decorator, we need a more general solution.

Answer (score 52):

I'm surprised that this question is so old and no one has taken the time to add the actual introspective way to do this, so here it is:

The code you want to inspect...

```
def template(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

baz = template
che = template

class Foo(object):
    @baz
    @che
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

Now you can inspect the above `Foo` class with something like this...

```
import ast
import inspect

def get_decorators(cls):
    target = cls
    decorators = {}

    def visit_FunctionDef(node):
        decorators[node.name] = []
        for n in node.decorator_list:
            name = ''
            if isinstance(n, ast.Call):
                name = n.func.attr if isinstance(n.func, ast.Attribute) else n.func.id
            else:
                name = n.attr if isinstance(n, ast.Attribute) else n.id

            decorators[node.name].append(name)

    node_iter = ast.NodeVisitor()
    node_iter.visit_FunctionDef = visit_FunctionDef
    node_iter.visit(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(target)))
    return decorators

print get_decorators(Foo)
```

That should print something like this...

```
{'bar': ['baz', 'che']}
```

or at least it did when I tested this with Python 2.7.9 real quick :)

Comment: Okay, this has problems in python 3 : (at least it seems to, and I'm sure I'm *not* the best person with knowledge of inspect/ast to comment with that level of certainty); basically I have a the code from what you have above, and `inspect.getsource()` seems to return with the spaces in front of the `def wrapper` , which then gives an unexpected indent error on the `ast.parse` call.

Comment: *ALSO* when i tried to demonstrate this using hte online run-script tools (which I think script rather then run from a file), I jsut get `OSError: source code not available` so I suspect there are instances (perhaps also bin runs) where this process won't work. Perhaps it won't work when bin-only runs of python exist?

Comment: Which version of python3? I just tested it in python 2.7.13 and python 3.6.4 (which are the versions I have on my computer) and they both worked fine. Also, I'm not sure this will work everywhere, but it's worked everywhere I've needed it. I could definitely see the online run-script having protections for modules like ast and inspect, and probably other things like opening files, since it is, by definition, a more contained environment.

Comment: Thanks for checking: I'll try to have another look but without being able to demonstrate with the nice helpful code sharing it makes it harder. If I can replicated it I'll open it up as a new question and tag you ;)

Comment: How would something in `decorator_list` not an instance of `ast.Call`? Is it necessary to check this?

Comment: @FishMonitor This is a perfect example of why it's great to comment the code with why something was done because I'm not sure why I added that check anymore. You can definitely remove the `ast.Call` check in your own code and see if you still get the desired results

Answer (score 13):

I've add the same question. In my unit tests I just wanted to make sure decorators were used by given functions/methods.

The decorators were tested separately so I didn't need to test the common logic for each decorated function, just that the decorators were used.

I finally came up with the following helper function:

```
import inspect

def get_decorators(function):
    """Returns list of decorators names

    Args:
        function (Callable): decorated method/function

    Return:
        List of decorators as strings

    Example:
        Given:

        @my_decorator
        @another_decorator
        def decorated_function():
            pass

        >>> get_decorators(decorated_function)
        ['@my_decorator', '@another_decorator']

    """
    source = inspect.getsource(function)
    index = source.find("def ")
    return [
        line.strip().split()[0]
        for line in source[:index].strip().splitlines()
        if line.strip()[0] == "@"
    ]
```

With the list comprehension, it is a bit "dense" but it does the trick and in my case it's a test helper function.

It works if you are intrested only in the decorators names, not potential decorator arguments. If you want to support decorators taking arguments, something like `line.strip().split()[0].split("(")[0]` could do the trick (untested)

Finally, you can remove the "@" if you'd like by replacing `line.strip().split()[0]` by `line.strip().split()[0][1:]`

Answer (score 1):

That's because decorators are "syntactic sugar". Say you have the following decorator:

```
def MyDecorator(func):
    def transformed(*args):
        print "Calling func " + func.__name__
        func()
    return transformed
```

And you apply it to a function:

```
@MyDecorator
def thisFunction():
    print "Hello!"
```

This is equivalent to:

```
thisFunction = MyDecorator(thisFunction)
```

You could embed a "history" into the function object, perhaps, if you're in control of the decorators. I bet there's some other clever way to do this (perhaps by overriding assignment), but I'm not that well-versed in Python unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 1):

As [Faisal notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232112), you could have the decorators themselves attach metadata to the function, but to my knowledge it isn't automatically done.

Answer (score 1):

`ast` can be used to parse source code.

```
import ast


with open('./tmp1.py') as f:
    code_text = f.read()


parsed = ast.parse(code_text)
```

Here's my attempt at parsing the parsed object for decorators. This implementation recursively searches for applied decorators. It'll capture usage of `@` on functions, classes and methods as well as when they're nested.

```
import ast


def flatten(decorator_list):
    for d in decorator_list:
        try:
            yield d.id
        except AttributeError:
            yield d.func.id


def parse_decorables(body, indent=0):
    for node in body:
        if isinstance(node, (ast.FunctionDef, ast.ClassDef)):
            print('    '*indent, node.name, '-', *flatten(node.decorator_list))
            parse_decorables(node.body, indent+1)


with open('./tmp1.py') as f:
    code_text = f.read()


parsed = ast.parse(code_text)
parse_decorables(parsed.body)
```

There's a few things to bear in mind when considering this question. A decorator may just add an attribute to the function and return it. At that point, there's no association between the decorator and the original function. Therefore, there's no way to dynamically inspect a function and ensure we're seeing all the decorators that were applied to it.

So we go to this `ast` solution and inspect the code. However, it has it's own limitations. An imported decorator may apply more decorators to the function, this will not catch that. If you 'apply a decorator' the way it was done before `@` was introduced (f = deco(f)), this will not catch that. So, really we're just capturing uses of `@` in the source file, which may be suitable for your application.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do in a general way, because

```
@foo
def bar ...
```

is exactly the same as

```
def bar ...
bar = foo (bar)
```

You may do it in certain special cases, like probably `@staticmethod` by analyzing function objects, but not better than that.

Answer (score -1):

That's not possible in my opinion. A decorator is not some kind of attribute or meta data of a method. A decorator is a convenient syntax for replacing a function with the result of a function call. See http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.4.html?highlight=decorators#pep-318-decorators-for-functions-and-methods for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can't but even worse is there exists libraries to help hide the fact that you have decorated a function to begin with.  See [Functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html) or the decorator library (`@decorator` if I could find it) for more information.