# __decorated__ for python decorators

Tags: python, c, parsing, compiler-construction, decorator

As of 2.4 (2.6 for classes), python allows you to decorate a function with another function:

```
def d(func): return func

@d
def test(first): pass
```

It's a convenient syntactic sugar.  You can do all sorts of neat stuff with decorators without making a mess.  However, if you want to find out the original function that got decorated you have to jump through hoops (like `Cls.method.__func__.__closure__[0].cell_contents` or worse).

I found myself wishing for a better way and found that there had been some discussion on python-dev about adding a variable called `__decorated__` to the [new] function returned by the decorator.  However, it appears that didn't go anywhere.

Being an adventuresome person, and having had pretty heavy python experience for about 4 years, I thought I would look into implementing `__decorated__` in the python compiler source, just to see how it goes.

To be honest I have never delved into the C underneath the hood, so my first hours have been just trying to make sense of how the underlying C code works.  So firstly, **what would be the best resources to get my head around what I would have to change/add for `__decorator__`?**

Secondly, if a decorator returns a new function then `__decorated__` would just return the original, decorated function.  However, if the decorator returns the original function, what should happen?  Here are three options I could think of (the third is my favorite):

1. Don't add `__decorator__`.
2. Add `__decorator__` but set it to None.
3. Add `__decorator__` and set it to the original function anyway.

So if it were to happen, **what do you think would be the best option?**

UPDATE:

Someone else [brought to my attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375573/finding-a-functions-parameters-in-python/3501316#3501316) a scenario that I had missed.  What happens when the decorator returns neither the original function nor a function that wraps the original?  At that point nothing is holding a reference to the original function and it will get garbage collected.  (Thanks [Oddthinking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8014/oddthinking)!)

So in that case, I think that I would still go with the third option.  The object returned by the decorator would gain a `__decorated__` name that references the original function.  This would mean that it would not be garbage-collected.

It seems weird to me that the function from a class definition would utterly disappear because you decorated it.  In my mind that is even more reason to have a `__decorated__` attribute applied for every decorator.  However, it's more likely that my intuition is faulty and that the current behavior is what most people would expect.  **Any thoughts?**

p.s. this is an extension of an earlier, more general [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375573/finding-a-functions-parameters-in-python) I had.  I also went for more info on the first part with a [separate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505029/extending-the-code-of-python-adding-language-features) post.

Comment: so you are thinking about the next step, i.e., how would the decorated function notice that it is decorated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109289/how-can-python-function-access-its-own-attributes :)

Comment: How would this work with `@property`? As in, decorators don't have to return functions at all.

Comment: @Aaron, I suppose you would add `__decorated__` to whatever is returned, function or not.

Comment: Note that, as of Python 3.2, functools.wraps automatically adds a __wrapped__ attribute pointing to the original function (http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools#functools.update_wrapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, independent of any discussion over whether this is a good idea, I'd go for option #3 because it's the most consistent: it always shows that the function has been decorated by the presence of the attribute, and accessing the value of the attribute always returns a function, so you don't have to test it against `None`.

You should also consider this, though: what would you propose to do about manual decoration? e.g.

```
def test(first): pass
test = d(test)
```

Regarding the first part of the question, I haven't looked at the Python interpreter source code very much so I wouldn't be able to point you to anything particularly useful.

Comment: I would think you would have to manually add the `__decorated__` attribute to the new function, which would be even uglier.

Answer (score 1):

i feel free to use some single underscored "private" attribute like `_mydecor`

possible multi-decorator solution:

```
def decorate(decoration): 
    def do_decor(func): 
        if hasattr(func, '_mydecor'): 
            func._mydecor.add(decoration) 
        else: 
            func._mydecor = set([decoration]) 
        return func 
    return do_decor 

def isDecorated(func, decoration): 
    return (decoration in getattr(func, '_mydecor', set())) 

@decorate('red') 
@decorate('green') 
def orangefunc(): pass 

print isDecorated(orangefunc, 'green') # -> True 
print isDecorated(orangefunc, 'blue')  # -> False
```

Comment: That works well if you control the decorator.  I suppose you could wrap the decorator to get this done when you don't control it.