# Detect Decorator in Python

Tags: python, django, django-views

In python, is it possible to detect if there is a decorator on another function?

Specifically, I'm trying (in django) to write some middleware that will detect if the view being processed has been wrapped in the @login_required decorator.

```
class SomeMiddleware(object):

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if has_decorator(view_func):
            print "this view was decorated"
```

What I'm trying to fill in is the "has_decorator" portion....

Is this possible?

Comment: Look this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232024/introspection-to-get-decorator-names-on-a-method

Comment: The answer on that question is a bad idea.  Don't make up your own special magic for applying decorators.

Comment: Thanks for the link but it isn't quite what I was looking for. I was hoping there was just some python function or attribute that was used for detecting the decorator.

Comment: In general, almost certainly not. A decorator is just a callable which takes some function, and replaces it with a new one. If you know something about the decorators that might be applied, you can check for their effects.

Comment: That's about what I'm finding...

Answer (score 3):

Just some quick fooling around in the shell shows that the `func_closure` attribute on a function is empty on undecorated functions, but contains data in decorated functions. Not 100% sure this is true all the time, but maybe this works out for you.

Comment: That's quite handy... that ends up returning to me with a set of "cells"... I'm having a hard time interfacing with those cells though. I can't seem to find examples of how to pull attributes/methods out of the cells... any advice?