# Introspect class property to see if it is decorated, without accessing property value

Tags: python, introspection, python-decorators

Here is a simplified version of what I am dealing with:

```
def mydecorator(prop):
    def wrapper(self_arg):
        return prop(self_arg) + 'bar'
    return wrapper

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 'foo'

    @property
    @mydecorator
    def foo(self):
        return self.value

    @property
    def doesnt_have_my_decorator(self):
        return 'something that requires a lot of computation'

f = Foo()

print f.foo # prints 'foobar'
```

Now what I would like to be able to do, is introspect `f.foo`, without actually accessing its value, and check if it is decorated with `@mydecorator`. Is this possible?

The use case is to be able whitelist a property as "safe" in a certain context, without actually accessing it's value in case it is "unsafe".

I have seen [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232189/3642398), but it seems like that method requires `foo` to have already been accessed.

I have found that I can see that it is a `property` with:

```
f.__class__.__dict__['foo'].__class__
```

but I haven't been able to find any references to `mydecorator`. Since it's Python, I am sure there is a way, but I haven't been able to figure it out so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python a decorator is merely a shortened syntax. E.g.:

```
@property
@mydecorator
def foo(self):
    return self.value
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
def foo(self):
    return self.value

foo = property (mydecorator (foo))
```

Since your decorator doesn't leave any detectable trace on its return value, it is not possible to determine if it was applied.  You could instead rewrite to e.g.:

```
def mydecorator(prop):
    def wrapper(self_arg):
        return prop(self_arg) + 'bar'
    wrapper._mydecorator = True
    return wrapper
```

and then use this expression to test it:

```
hasattr (type (f).foo.fget, '_mydecorator')
```

Comment: While hacking through it I almost got there. I made it as far as setting `wrapper._mydecorator = True` as you did, but I couldn't figure out how to find that attribute. This got me all the way there. Thanks so much!