# How do I show the command checks for a command?

Tags: discord.py

When you declare a command, you know how there are those `@commands.has_permissions()` things right? I'm trying to make a command that shows the checks for a command, but I'm not sure how to continue. Here is my code so far:

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['sp'])
async def showperms(self, ctx, *, command_name):
    """Shows the permissions needed for a command"""

    com = self.bot.get_command(command_name)
    print(com.checks)
```

When I do this for a command, I get this output:

```py
[<function bot_has_permissions.<locals>.predicate at 0x7fd64b5ff940>, <function has_permissions.<locals>.predicate at 0x7fd64b5ff550>]
```

I believe it uses Discord's permission integers, but pretty much no one knows how to use those. I'm not sure how I can 'translate' this into something I can send, such as `manage_messages` or `administrator.` The command I used to test has these checks btw:

```py
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
@commands.bot_has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [`discord.py` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the [`Command.checks` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command.checks), you'll see this:

> A list of predicates that verifies if the command could be executed with the given Context as the sole parameter.

What is a predicate, you ask? [Functional Programming HOWTO: Built-In Functions, A. M. Kuchling](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#built-in-functions):

> “A predicate is a function that returns the truth value of some condition.”

So, with the list returned by `Command.checks`, you can't really do much.

To get each of the checks on your function, you would probably have to iterate through the decorators wrapping the function. I myself don't know how to do that, but you can find a good example of doing so in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232024/introspection-to-get-decorator-names-on-a-method).

Comment: ohh okay. ill look into that question. Thank you!!